# Form validation on the fly

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to search on this stuff but I could barely found a good resource since I can't think of a specific keyword to search. I have also searched here but I can't find something that is easy to comprehend and fits directly to my question.

It goes like this. I wanted to make my form validated before submission. In this case, I was wondering if I could use a jquery function if it's available that the user can't click the submit button until the form is valid.

Is there a way that I could implement the thing I said? If so? Will jquery be usable?

Thank you so much for future replies.

Comment: Just to be sure: Client side validation will be additional to server side validation?

Comment: there are plugins that can do the validation for you google the term `jquery form validation` and you will get plenty of options

Comment: here is a **fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6gCRF/7/** it might help you it uses [**bassistance plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Marissa below gave me a link and I shall try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery validation plugin - see the first example http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: Thank you for you very specific suggestion. I gave downloaded the plugin and I gotta try this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were googling, but I just did "jquery validation" and came up with numerous searches.

One was: http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/ with many different types of examples.  You can go the bassistance.de route, which I initially looked at but I found it was too heavy and didn't cover many aspects, so I essentially rolle my own.

Yes you can do validation on the fly and only submit when all input has been validated clientside.  The beauty of doing it with jquery is you can also do an ajax post to then have some serverside validation done and then give the response back to jquery and mark fields invalid if they don't pass further tests.  All without that annoying postback!

Comment: Hello. I actually did found some stuff but they were not that understandable. I am using CodeIgniter and it has a form validation class. I was uncertain if I should use jquery even if CI has a validation but have to submit the form then redirect back if it's not valid. That's why I opted to look for Jquery validation stuff. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: I'm using CI as well.  You use Jquery to provide on-demand validation and then use the form validation as backup, also because CI provides sanitation and xss cover.